# How to send HTML emails from EMM

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot, wso2-esb

From the emm\configuration console, we can INVITE users to join the organization; an email is sent with the URL to register to EMM server.
That email is sent in plain text format:     Content-Type: text/plain
How ca we have it sent in HTML format:     Content-Type: text/html

```
    Subject: EMM Enrollment
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_83553467.1444441352245"        
     ------=_Part_0_83553467.1444441352245

    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Comment: I also tried to update the axis2.xml file following this example: http://heshans.blogspot.ca/2010/10/send-html-format-email-from-wso2-esb.html

Comment: Still no success though...

Answer (score 3):

Kindly follow the below link for configuring the server prior to generating emails. For an example we need to configure the axis2.xml to specify a mail client on /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/General+Server+Configurations

The Document https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Sending+Enrollment+Invitations+to+Users as details of how we can send enrollment information to the user. This document has the  REST API call that can be invoked for the purpose.

For an example, we can use a curl command as below  to generate the invitation.

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 33392fb365b3ac693b405b565ddc8a3a" -d @'user.json' -k -v https://localhost:9443/mdm-admin/users/email-invitation

Regards,Shavantha